# How to create every possible sub sample of size n from an overall sample of size N?

Tags: r

I have a total data set with N points, in the form of a list of numerical values. I need N-choose-n unique sub samples of size n from this data set. I have no idea how that can be done. Does anyone know how? I'd like the result to be a list of lists, with each sub list being a sub sample. Thank you.

Comment: For the best chance of getting help, please read [How to write a good R question with a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/12109788) and update your question accordingly. Good luck!

Comment: Can you put together a reproducible example and show us what you've tried?  Specifically, what have you tried that can be easily found by typing "[r] n choose k" in the search bar above?  In particular, look at `combn()`.

Answer (score 1):

For a given `n`,

```
df = head(mtcars)
n = 3
my_list = combn(seq_len(nrow(df)), m = n, FUN = \(i) df[i, ])
length(my_list)
# [1] 20
```

The above gives a list of data frames, all unique subsets of `df` with 3 rows.

If you want to iterate over all possible subset sizes, we can wrap that in `lapply` to get a list of lists of data frames for each `n` value:

```
my_big_list = lapply(
  X = 1:nrow(df),
  FUN = \(n) combn(seq_len(nrow(df)), m = n, FUN = \(i) df[i, ], simplify = FALSE)
)
length(my_big_list)
# [1] 6
lengths(my_big_list)
# [1]  6 15 20 15  6  1
```

This will end up duplicating your data many times. It would probably be much more efficient to make a list of indices and subset your data dynamically for each combination as it is used, rather than storing all the copies of your data. Or if the number of rows is very large, then there are more efficient solutions that don't store more in memory than what you are using in packages like `arrangements` and `RcppAlgos`.

Comment: I may be wrong about this, but I think with the `iterators` package, you will still have to have a "complete" object in memory in order to iterate. For example, I don't think there is any way to force `combn` to give one result at a time with the `nextElem` paradigm from `iterators`.

Comment: This is quite interesting... started to digg and found this: [iter.default..state$obj](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/iterators/blob/c8e06481cf5752833172ef25d37fd74eea00c19b/R/iterators.R#L31C19-L31C19). It is actually quite clever. It stores the entire object in a new environment so it appears that the iterator leaves a small foot print when you check `object.size(it <- iter(...))` however checking `object.size(it$state$obj))` reveals the real load. Regardless, the entire object must be generated in order to be utilized.

Comment: @JosephWood good to know, thank you! I've only used `iterators` once or twice years ago. I've always assumed there would be a package providing a nice way to create a stable mapping between the first n integers and a complete set of combinations or permutations, so that you could reliably and consistently access one of them at a time or a subset of them (say a random sample of them) without ever needing to load in memory more than you are using. But I guess `iterators` isn't anything even close to that!

Comment: There is!! The package `arrangements` provides combinatorial iterators. It utilizes `R6` and has a `getnext` method. E.g. `it <- icombination(10, 5); it$getnext()` There is also my package `RcppAlgos`. For standard combinations and permutations, there are iterators that offer bidirectional transversal as well as random access. E.g. `it2 <- comboIter(10, 5); it2@nextIter(); it2@back(); it2$prevIter(); it2[[10]]`. Both packages keep memory low and only generate what is requested, saving the state internally.

Comment: Ah, so I remembered the term "iterators" correctly, it's just not the package of that name! Thanks again!